# what do we mean when we declare struct node *p = NULL;?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

This probably is a dumb question but I just started linked lists and was confused.

when we declare:

```
typedef struct node{

    int data;
    struct node *next;

}node;    

node *p = NULL;
```

which part of the `node` is `NULL`? Is it `p->next`?

Comment: `p` is a pointer, and the value of that pointer is `NULL`, meaning it's not pointing to any valid `node`.

Comment: No is not p->next to have no value, is p that has no value! :)

Comment: I'd recommend you go back and read more about pointers before tackling linked lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer is set to NULL, basically it means that the pointer is pointing to nothing valid. If you try to do `p->next` you are in undefined behavior territory, i.e. your program can continue working or crash or anything in between.

I can assume that setting the pointer to NULL means, in your case, creating an empty list.